# Laravel: Blank CSS Files on deployed project

Tags: php, css, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to figure out why all the CSS and Javascript files are being display as empty files on a Laravel 5.6 project running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Plesk 17.5 Server Onyx. This happened after deployment.

I was reading a couple of old questions and I've tried most of the solutions without any luck:

> **Note #1**:
>
> Only CSS and Javascript files are displayed as empty files, routing works fine for other files.

**Attempts made so far**:

1. Moved the file `.htaccess` from `public` to the root project folder.
2. Added `guo+w` permissions to `storage` and `bootstrap/cache`
3. Used `mix('css/app.css')` and `asset('themes/default/css/style.css')` to access to CSS & JS files. I've also tried relative and full-qualified paths.

> **Note #2**:
>
> If I access in the URL with `public/path/file.css` I can see the file proplery. But whenever I change from `mix('css/app.css')` to `mix('public/css/app.css')` I get ***Undefined Index*** when I set the `debug=true`.

Well, maybe there are more attempts that I don't remember right now. Any suggestions to solve this "issue"?

Comment: Try and re compile your assets using: npm run build

Comment: I get `npm ERR! missing script: build`

Comment: npm run production

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: Nope, I  don't get any errors but nothing changes.